# How can one's Year Reputation be greater than Total Reputation?

Tags: bug

http://stackexchange.com/leagues/327/year/worldbuilding/2016-01-01/17179#17179

At the moment, user fi12 who has been a member for 4 months has a Total of 1675 (lagged from his live value of 1680) and a Year rep of 1735?

Comment: The account was created this year, so it's not a year-boundary thing.  He's also offered no bounties, so it's not that.  If the difference were 100 I might wonder if the association bonus doesn't count, but it doesn't seem to be that.  I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 2):

1. Downvotes could be subtracted when considering the total reputation: Unless some have been reversed overtime, I counted about 33 in negative reputation.
2. He got 30 points in the last hours. The reputation league probably updates with a script that runs once every few hours.

Comment: You're suggesting that the different leagues are not updated at the same time? But, the number on the person's own page is current.  The graph didn't show major losses in the last day, which is what would be necessary for this to be explained by having the Total more out of date than the Year.

Answer (score 1):

With a downvote total of 195, he's one of the most discriminating posters here. I wish more of us had the discipline. It also accounts for why the poster's all-round rep gain total is significantly higher than the current reputation.